# Proving $E(X)=0 \Rightarrow P(X=0)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value

> Let $X$ be a random variable that takes on values in $[0,\infty]$. I
> want to show that $E(X)=0$ implies $P(X=0)=1$.

I came up with an attempt presupposing that $X$ is discrete. We have:$$\mathbb{E}(X)=\sum \limits_{\omega\in [0,\infty]}X(\omega)P(\{\omega\})=\sum \limits_{k=0}^{\infty}kP(X=k)=0\cdot P(X=0)+\underbrace{1\cdot P(X=1)+2\cdot P(X=2)+\cdots }_{=0}=0$$ And on the other hand $\sum \limits_{k=0}^{\infty}P(X=k)=1$, this means $P(X=0)$. Is this correct? And what about the continuous case?

Comment: Not  every r.v. is discrete and you cannot use sums to evaluate expectations.

Comment: By Markov 's inequality, for every $\lambda > 0$, $P(X \geq \lambda) \leq \frac{1}{\lambda}E(X) = 0$. Let $\lambda \searrow 0$ to get $P(X > 0) = 0$.

Comment: Mason, I like your solution. But if $E(X)=0$ what do you mean by $E(X)/\lambda$? Isn't that just $0/\lambda=0$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $$X \ge \frac1k {\bf 1}_{\{X \ge 1/k\}} \,,$$
taking expectations gives
$$0=E(X) \ge \frac1k P(X \ge 1/k) \,.$$
Finally, by subadditivity
$$P(X>0) \le \sum_k P(X \ge 1/k)=0 \,.$$